# Objective -c POST request not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, post, uiwebview

i develop program which searches for similar images(Reverse image search)
My Code:

```
Y_request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];
[Y_request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
[Y_request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
[Y_request setTimeoutInterval:30];
[Y_request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];


NSString *Y_boundary=@"myBoucndary";
NSString *Y_FileParamConstant=@"upfile";
Y_requestURL = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"https://www.yandex.com/images/search"];

NSString *Y_contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",Y_boundary];
[Y_request setValue:Y_contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

Y_body = [NSMutableData data];



NSDictionary *Y_params=@{
                         @"format":@"",
                         @"request":@"[{\"block\":\"b-page_type_search-by-image__link\"}]",
                         @"rpt":@"imageview"
                         };
for (NSString *Y_param in Y_params) {
    [Y_body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",Y_boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [Y_body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", Y_param] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [Y_body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", [Y_params objectForKey:Y_param]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}
```

//    add image data

```
NSData *Y_imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageSearch, 0.1);
if (Y_imageData) {
    [Y_body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", Y_boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [Y_body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"image.jpeg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [Y_body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [Y_body appendData: Y_imageData];
    [Y_body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

}
[Y_body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", Y_boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


[Y_request setHTTPBody:Y_body];
[Y_request  setURL:Y_requestURL];
[_myWebView loadRequest:Y_request];
```

This Yandex Search query. This query works only on the iPhone but does not work for Ipad,Why?.
Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Do you get an error output on iPad ?

Comment: Failed to load image in Yandex page, Not view ipad

Comment: In your situation I would implement `UIWebViewDelegate` and look in the `-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*)webView` why it doesnt work. At least then you get some kind of error output on the request. There could be 100s of reasons why it doesnt work. For example if I see the `https` there possibly could be a `SSLHandshakeError` if you´re using iOS 9. But that´s just a guess, as I said, get some error output.

Comment: You did not understand me, the picture is not loaded on the server

Comment: yes I dont understand you. Can you say which line of code fails? You mean the site loads but the images doesnt display?

Comment: that's what gives when sending pictures to the server method POST http://pixs.ru/showimage/IMG0157PNG_3055386_19895328.png